# Ring of regular functions over union of open sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

In what generality does the ring of regular functions of a scheme $X$ over a finite union of open sets equal the intersection of the regular functions over respective open set? That is what properties of $X, U, V$ with open sets $U, V \subset X$ give $$\mathscr{O}_X(U \cup V) = \mathscr{O}_X(U) \cap \mathscr{O}_X(V)?$$

Comment: In order to talk about an intersection of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(V)$, you need some set that they're both a subset of. What are you picking to play this role?

Comment: I'm guessing that puts a requirement on them being subrings of a function field?

Comment: Certainly having a function field that contains all of the rings in sight does make things easier. In particular, that's why you can develop the theory of varieties fairly far without having to bring sheaves into play.